# Recover deleted folder in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have accidentally deleted one folder from the Google Cloud Storage.
How can I recover this folder?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot recover from that:

> Warning: Object deletion cannot be undone. Cloud Storage is designed to give developers a high amount of flexibility and control over their data, and Google maintains strict controls over the processing and purging of deleted data. To protect yourself from mistakes, see Deleting data best practices.

[GCP storage docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects)

Take a look at the [best practices documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#deleting) concerning deleting objects.

Comment: This is totally unacceptable. Even in GSuite if a user deletes a file from the recycle bin, it is recoverable for a couple of weeks. Google Storage should have data recovery mechanisms that could retain deleted files and folders for some time to enable data recovery. Big flaw.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment here but to complement Henrik Pingel's answer, there is an [object versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) feature that would allow you to plan ahead of time against accidental deletion of objects, although it is not enabled by default, it is a good practice to enable it straight away after creating buckets.

Answer (score 0):

We've got this after raising an issue through our paid subscription.

> We would be happy to assist you in the restoration process, but as a caveat we're required to communicate with you that the restoration operation on Google Cloud Storage is done once per customer. Henceforth you (your organization by extension) won't be able to use the restoration process again. We would also like to mention that this is a very tedious process which has to be done manually and recovery of any deleted data is not guaranteed.

Don't store important data on Google Cloud Storage.