# Deleted everything from google cloud - Can it be recovered?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google, database-restore

I recently deleted everything from my google cloud storage and need to know if there is a way to recover the data.

Comment: Reach out to Google's GCP support ASAP, but there are no guarantees.

Comment: **Object deletion cannot be undone.** https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects

Comment: This answer might be relevant: https://serverfault.com/a/1063324/437769